# Change color of image using css?

Tags: css, image, html

Is it possible to change the color of an image using only CSS?

(I'm using the transparent backgrounded glyphicons, and I need different symbol [not background] colors for my theme)

Comment: have a look at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430343/how-can-the-colors-of-an-image-be-changed-using-css3

Answer (score 1):

You can use image tints, but I don't know if it's going to give you the effect you expect:

Basically you wrap a `<figure>` element around your `<img/>` and apply styling to it:

```
/*HTML*/
<figure class="tint">  
  <img src="icon.png" width="400" height="260">  
</figure> 

/*CSS*/
.tint {  
    position: relative;  
    float: left;  
    cursor: pointer;  
}  

.tint:before {  
    content: "";  
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    background: rgba(0,255,255, 0.5);  
    -moz-transition: background .3s linear;  
    -webkit-transition: background .3s linear;  
    -ms-transition: background .3s linear;  
    -o-transition: background .3s linear;  
    transition: background .3s linear;  
}  

.tint:hover:before {  
    background: none;  
}
```

Check the [link](http://jsbin.com/igahay/1/edit) for a demo and full code samples.

On this [website](http://www.impressivewebs.com/image-tint-blend-css/) you can also check out some different methods.

Comment: Of course, this is only if you use `<img/>` tags. Otherwise, if it's a background in CSS, I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Thanks, but that does background as well (which I can get by appending e.g.: with `style="background-color: red"` to the parent tag).

Answer (score 0):

No. As these are image icons you can not change their color. You can try using these http://www.entypo.com/. As these are fonts they can easily change colors.